# Large size of JSON -models

Tags: json, model, export, three.js, blender

Heya allknowing Stackoverflow oracles!

Once more i must prey your guidance with exporting JSON models from blender.

I'v made some progress ( <- thanks to you) with my project and it feels too heavy to open it to public before i can fix some issues.

Sure all my models now look like they should but they're incredible large in size.

for example a simple model i made weights somewhat like 500 kb + texture size. you can see the picture below.

[image: simple robot head]

and the export settings.

[image: My blender export settings]

If i check the Truncate option, it'll make weird artefacts to the model.

Do i have to just live with it or is there a solution to lighten the model size somehow?

Thanks, Jukka Korhonen

Comment: at first glance your model looks pretty low-poly so I assume it's the texture that needs a bit of optimisation. Also I'm assuming the antenna is a lathe with not to many segments (if not, it should)

Comment: model indeed has under 50 polys, but the size 500kb? let see if i have dosen of those in one page, wouldn't it take age to load the page with slow internet connection? Not that its ment to be browsed with slow connections ;P

Comment: I guess there is no way to lighten them anymore :)

Comment: could you share the blender model ?

Comment: i might have accidentally forgot to save it o.Ô but if there is any of Blender > Three.js experts around that could tell what's the avg size of exported model(without textures), i'd be delighted :]